# Get has_one relation in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a `DataObject` called `Applicant` and it `$has_one` `Member` (this is the SilverStripe `Member` class).

```
private static $has_one = array (
    'MemberApplicant' => 'Member'
);
```

When a member is logged in and visits the `ApplicationPage` I want to be able to populate the form based on the members `Applicant` data.

I can make this work but I feel like I should be able to access the data easier.

Here is what I do:

```
$memberID = Member::currentUserID();
$applicant = Applicant::get()->filter('MemberApplicantID', $memberID)->first();

$form->loadDataFrom($applicant);
```

Shouldn't I be able to instantiate a `Member` and then call its relative `$MemberApplicant`?

Comment: So one Applicant has one Member related, and vice versa? Does one Member exactly have one Applicant? Is Applicant - Member it a 1:1 relation or a 1:n relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't I be able to instantiate a Member and then call its relative $MemberApplicant?

Of course. I assume you have a 1:1 relation, then you have to define the counter part on `Member` using `$belongs_to` (see [this diagram](http://www.silverstrip.es/blog/diagram-of-relationships-in-silverstripe/))

```
class Applicant extends DataObject
{
private static $has_one = [
    'MemberApplicant' => 'Member'
];
...

class MemberApplicantExtenension extends DataExtension
{
private static $belongs_to = [
    'Applicant' => 'Applicant'
];

...
```

Now add the DataExtension to the Member object in /mysite/_config/config.yml

```
Member:
  extensions:
    - MemberApplicantExtenension
```

and run a dev/build?flush.

Now you're able to get the related Applicant from the Member using built in ORM magic:

```
//Get the current Member
$member = Member::CurrentUser();

//get the $belongs_to
$applicant = $member->Applicant();
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to be able to avoid an "additional" ORM query by going through the current user's `Member` record, however this is not how SilverStripe (Or any system that uses SQL `JOIN`s works).

When you add a `$has_one` to a class, you essentially add a foreign key to that class's table. In your case it will be called `MemberApplicantID`, which is a foreign key to the Member table's primary key - its `ID` field. Thus your ORM query needs to go through an `Applicant` instance first.

Caveat: The above is not entirely true, `DataObject` does allow you to define a private (SilverStripe config) static `$belongs_to` on your model classes which lets you query "The other way around". I've never actually done this before, but it does look like you'd declare this on a custom `DataExtension` that decorates `Member` and has a value of "Applicant". See `DataObject::belongsToComponent()`.

You can also simplify your existing ORM query slightly without having to instantiate a `DataList` explicitly, but the route to your target data remains the same:

```
// SilverStripe >= 3.2
$applicant = DataObject::get_one('Applicant', array('MemberApplicantID = ?' => $memberID));

// SilverStripe < 3.2
$applicant = DataObject::get_one('Applicant', '"MemberApplicantID" = ' . $memberID);
```